# Can I use Android floating action button using Android Official Library?

Tags: android, android-library, floating-action-button, android-design-library

not the others Library,

I want to use 'Android Official library' like v7, support library anything else.

I have a NEXUS7 and I want to use floating action button with Listview.

So... How can I use floating action button?

Comment: Now you can use the official Design Support Library:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483210/is-there-a-native-component-for-the-floating-action-button-in-android-material-d/30527761#30527761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of late May, 2015, the [FloatingActionButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) is now standardized and officially part of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).  I wrote up a quick [usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/example-of-using-floatingactionbutton-with-support-library/30584075#30584075) if that helps at all...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not included (yet) on the official support library. You have to use a 3rd party library for FloatingActionButtons

There are many, this one is the most popular: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: I need the jar version for integration with eclipse

Comment: Anybody have the Jar version?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for appcompat support library.

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html