# Is there a native component for the Floating action button in Android Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library, floating-action-button

My question revolves around the [**Floating action button**](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) that was introduced in Android Material Design.

[image]

There are many library offering this component on GitHub as:

1. [Android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)
2. [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)
3. [CircularFloatingActionMenu](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu)
4. [Fab](https://github.com/shell-software/fab)
5. [Floating-action-button](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button)

But my question is:

Is there a native component with the last release of `android.support.vX` that was built for `Floating action button`?

Components such as :

- android.support.v7.cardview
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
- ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Today (29/05/2015) it is officially avaiable with the new Material Design support Library.

Just add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Add this view to your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
```

And use it:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //TODO
    }
});
```

Comment: How to add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` in eclipse ?

Answer (score 5):

Not yet, there have been hints that we will see it in the next support lib.

Comment: Thank you. Where you hear this information please (video, article...)?

Comment: Someone on http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/ was looking through the updated GoogleIO that is available on github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class md-fab on a md-button then add a span with something like a plus sign inside of the md-button.  Also there are other md-fab classes like md-fab-bottom-right which might help you out.  Also you can use an md-icon inside your md-button

```
<md-button class="md-fab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" /></md-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are now out of date.

FABS are available as part of Material Components for Android:
https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Here is the class: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton

Don't miss the Catalog app with working examples:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android