# How to create a circle button in the right bottom corner on Android 5+?

Tags: android, user-interface

Is there any standard tools or existing libraries to create a circle button like on Gmail App?
[image]

Comment: Its called the Floating Action Button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483210/is-there-a-native-component-for-the-floating-action-button-in-android-material-d/30527761#30527761

Answer (score 3):

In the android support design support library one of the widgets provided is the Floating Action Button, which is usually added in the bottom right corner(but need not be used only there)

> A floating action button is a round button denoting a primary action
>   on your interface. The Design library’s FloatingActionButton gives you
>   a single consistent implementation, by default colored using the
>   colorAccent from your theme.

To get the android design support library in your build.gradle file, add this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

In your layout file"

```
<RelativeLayout
 ...
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Details of android design support library [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Also there are many other libraries providing the FAB like

- https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton
- https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 2):

1.First important thing use Android Studio

2.Add as a dependency to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}
```

3. Create a layout

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />
```

4.Add the namespace

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your layout file.

5. You can also Set the button type (normal or mini) via the fab_type xml attribute (default is normal):

`fab:fab_type="mini"`

or

`fab.setType(FloatingActionButton.TYPE_MINI);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the new [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) a default implementation of the floating action button is provided [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog).

In order to have access to the new FAB class you will need to add this dependency to your gradle build file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```