# FloatingActionButton class could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout

After taking a look at the new methods in Material Design, I tried to implement a Floating Action Button in an app. However, I am getting this error in my preview (Previewing Android version 21):

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
(First paragraph of error)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompatLollipop.setTintList(DrawableCompatLollipop.java:56)
at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat$LollipopDrawableImpl.setTintList(DrawableCompat.java:145)
at android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.java:270)
etc...
```

Anyone have any idea? This is my build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "owensetiawan.tutorials.fab"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

It would be absolutely fantastic if someone could help me shed some light on my problem.

Comment: Many people have reported having issues with the new FAB button (widget) - I would suggest you use one of the popular libraries meanwhile (I did this) until the FAB button bugs are fixed

Comment: @Eenvincible Really? Oh well, then I hope Google fixes this soon. Meanwhile, any good libraries you can recommend?

Comment: I used this in my recently published app : https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: I am getting the same error in the preview pane but it compiles without any error and even works on the device. This is definitely a bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: These issues are explained very well here : http://antonioleiva.com/floating-action-button/

Answer (score 5):

Hey i got the same problem with the instantiated of design library and solved it by this

Step 1 > code for fab

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/search"
      app:backgroundTint="@color/color_fav"
      app:borderWidth="0dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      />
```

step 2  > dependency

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1"
```

step 3 > the main step for above problem

easy one:- go to your xml and click on preview and in the bar in preview select AP1 21

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the **VERSION** for **AppCompat Library** and the **Design Support Library** is the **same**. This is mostly an internal dependency conflict, keeping both versions same fixed it for me :-

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue updated "Android Support Library"(22.2.1). Read my answer for same type of issue.
[Cannot setup floating action buttons as class cannot be found (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739012/cannot-setup-floating-action-buttons-as-class-cannot-be-found-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, simply change the Manifest from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="victor.com.ec.gastos_diarios">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActividadPrincipal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="victor.com.ec.gastos_diarios">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity 
            android:name=".ActividadPrincipal"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```