# The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I receive the following error

> The following classes could not be instantiated: -
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Lately that problem appears every time I opened new project in Android Studio,
I tried many solutions written here, like ..

- Rebuild and re-sync project with gradle option.
- Change Android rendering version.
- Checking updates and install latest version.

None of those solutions work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to update tools and sdk also? Sorry for annoying, but this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739012/cannot-setup-floating-action-buttons-as-class-cannot-be-found-android-studio

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev yes I did that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is changing project theme in **res/values/styles.xml**

```
<stylename="AppTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try update "build.gradle (Module.app)" like this:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
...
```

and resync project. It helped me