# Rendering Problems after gradle sync process complete

Tags: android, build.gradle

When i try to create a new application show me error like this

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE 
>   Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   Unable to find resource ID #0x1080029   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)   at
>   android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)   at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:70)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:39)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:65)
>   at
>   android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:37)
>   at
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:109)
>   at
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:105)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

Comment: show the xml and code related to your floating action button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924773/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-design-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your all support library which is added in app level **build.gradle** file.

After the update and completed gradle sync process try to remove the loaded cache from the android studio you can do it from

**File (Menu) -> Invalidate cashes and restart then choose invalidate and restart(Dialog).**

Hope this solves your problem.