# Floating Action Button Without Checkable

Tags: java, android, interface, floating-action-button

I've been following this code example from Google about the Floating Action Button in the newest Android library http://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html

This works, as a Checkable button. However, I don't want it to be checkable, I just want to be able to click it and animate it as you'd expect (seems strange the Google example is for a checkable button when it seems like it'd be against their design principles, and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876515/onclick-for-floating-action-button) have had problems)

I'm reasonably new to Android, and so far my research has come up with a lot of external libraries, but I'm trying to keep it as native as possible

Is there an interface in Android Java that would allow me to essentially use this as a button? The FAB button example is `Checkable` and obviously the constructors and methods pertain to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jmo : Please check [Android Floating Action Button based on Material Design specification](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) And [NQH_FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/huy510cnt/NQH_FloatingActionButton) For sample Purpose . I hope this link will help you http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html), part of the official [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).