# FAB Color for backgroundTint not changing in Gingerbread version devices

Tags: android, material-design, android-2.3-gingerbread, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

I am facing an issue while changing backgroundTint color in xml for FAB, that the color has not assigned for devices with Gingerbread versions. I am really confused and don't know why it is behaving weird. I am completely stuck with this issue with a couple of hours triggering out the solution but I couldn't. Kindly help me with your tips and suggestions to resolve my issue. I am posting my code and screen shot of the issue for your reference. Thanks in advance.

**include_fab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

**Design support library in my gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

**Screenshot of versions** **GingerBread** and **KitKat**

**Note**: I am getting exact output of my requirement above GingerBread devices. Problem arises with GingerBread alone.

[image]

Comment: I'm having similar problems, it also causes crashes. Are you using Genymotion?

Comment: Using both but i didnt try this in genymotion.

Comment: I dont have genymotion gingerbread versions, but it is working fine with latest versions in genymotion

Comment: I only noticed this on gingerbread Genymotion, wondering if this might be a Genymotion issue.

Comment: no yar in device also this issue is replicating.

Comment: It seems like this issue was not present in support design v22

Comment: yes of course. you are right. It is really a critical one that should be sorted out because still GingerBread users are in practice. Around 20 percent of the people overall uses GingerBread.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30609927/3922207

Comment: I have this same issue on hardware (T-Mobile HTC myTouch 4g running 2.3) and on a normal 2.3 emulator, so don't blame genymotion. I think it may be a generic gingerbread problem.

Comment: @jordan.roskelley yes u r right. It is not genymotion issue. I recently tested with Samsung-S2 and same problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

It may work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FloatingActionButton v = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{0xffff0000});
        v.setSupportBackgroundTintList(csl);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. will check and let you know

Comment: @Chandru do it work for you, if yes, please accept answer so that other people get correct answer, ask if any query do you have. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug in the library. There is an open bug report that you can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183315).