# Why does my FloatingActionButton have ripple effect even in resting state?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, rippledrawable

I don't know why there is a ripple effect even in the resting state of my FAB(FloatingActionButton).
This is how it looks:
[image: Inappropriate FAB]

This is my implementation in xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/white_plus"
    android:id="@+id/plusIcon"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:paddingEnd="0dp"
    app:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: This post may helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30609927/3922207

Comment: Yes, I tried using color/transparent but not change.
Also, I am not setting the rippleColor dynamically.

Comment: Just to clarify on my previous comment - that link did not help me. :(

Answer (score 1):

This problem was coming because I had set the colorAccent to #af18cccc and, hence, it was not completely opaque.
After changing the colorAccent to #ff18cccc, it was working perfectly.
For bringing the transparency effect, I called setAlpha(0.8) from the java code.
Now, it works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Sid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33449813), you can also call

```
android:alpha = "0.8"
```

directly in XML.