# build error: Unable to find a particular resource

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, compiler-errors

when i run the below code i get this error and get it with multiple positions but with this code usually mean when i write code like this

```
C:\Users\saad\Desktop\Sa2d\Android\JustJava\app\src\main\java\com\example\android\justjava\MainActivity.java
Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

this my code on "content_main.xml"

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Quantity"/>
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="0"/>
   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Order"
       android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

and this my code on "MainActivity.java"
i am mark the error line with *

```
`*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });`
```

what is the solution for this problem ???

Comment: Your layout doesn't have any `FloatingActionButton` with id `fab`.

Comment: yes i observe thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//etc..
```

Is refer to `FloatingActionButton`, so probably you have deleted the code on xml file and then you have to delete the code (java) relative to Fab or you can add:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

on your layout.xml

Answer (score 2):

Add a floating action button to your layout called `fab`.

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your layout doesn't have any `FloatingActionButton` with id `fab`.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file, add this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

more reference

[FloatingActionButton example with Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding following Gradle dependency:

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

followed by gradle sync.

Comment: Same answer given by me 10 minutes ago.. what`s extra points you added?