# Does floating Action button works back from 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, floating-action-button

I am implementing floating action button in my application. And the target is 23 and i need to know whether it can run on android device with 4.0 version of android.

Comment: Why don't you test it on a virtual device that runs android 4 and find out?

Comment: I have tried that and it dint work for me. So I need to know whether its problem of my phone or 4,0 does not support FAB

Comment: You need to use the support version of FAB to use it on older devices

Comment: Okay, Thank you and can you please list out what are the support versions of fab that are to be implemented

Comment: Just add `compile "com.android.support:design:22.2.0"` to your `dependencies` block in your `build.gradle` file in your `app` module, not the global `build.gradle` file. Note the version number, use the mist current one.

Comment: i got this error when i tried using it

Comment: Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Comment: actually i was using com.android.support:design-v4:22.2.2 before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library