# Setting pressedTranslationZ in FloatingActionButton programmatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button

The `pressedTranslationZ` attribute seems to be available only in xml and cannot be set programmatically. Will creating a custom `FloatingActionButton` solve this problem? What are the possible alternatives?

Comment: hope your answer will available here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library

Answer (score 2):

If you read in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/909ea305d2d5c1cc969372f46e8f196022836f99/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#128) of `FloatingActionButton`, the `pressedTranslationZ` is set on the special implementation class, which is a private property, so you will not be able to access it using inheritance.

Your two options are using the XML property, or using Java reflection.

Drawbacks of the second option are that it might break with the updates of the design library, and it is not sure if changing using reflection will surely change the button itself too (it might be a property which is set before drawing and untouched after that).

Comment: The amount of vertical change when the button is pressed. It looks like it is coming forward.