# How to handle Floating Menu Action in landscape mode

Tags: android, configuration, material-design

I tried to make FlaationActionButton using [floating action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library)

Then I came across three scenarios:

1. Need to handle landscape and portrait mode for Phones

   Working fine for Portrait mode but some Floating actions not visible when changing the configuration to landscape mode.
2. Tablet --- should expand upwards both in landscape and portrait mode:
   Working fine.
3. Phone--- In Portrait: should expand upwards
           In Landscape: nexpand left if floating action button is in right bottom corner.

I am facing the problem when Floating buttons are more than 5.

Below are the images:

**Working fine in Portrait mode:**

[image]

**Need like this in landscape mode:**

[image]

Comment: Really liked the idea of ordering them horizontally when orientation mode is landscape, is it material design solution for lots of floating action buttons or your design workaround?

Answer (score 1):

> I am facing the problem when Floating buttons are more than 5.

You need to create different layout for landscape mode as per documentation:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

For implementing same design for different screen sizes and different orientation you need to implement xml files. You can see the structure as below:
[image]

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW Ok.