# Does android native support items to Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to create a floating action button with  items like the picture. & also add some text beside the item. The picture is taken from **[google website](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions)**. But i found some libraries to solve the problem. like [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) & [this](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)  I am pretty much curious about android native design libraries. Any one have idea how to make possible with native library?

Picture:

[image]

Update: Code i written

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // my actions is here 
        }
    });
```

Xml are as follows

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_behavior="com.alhikmah.weather360.utility.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FloatingActionButton example with Support Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library)

Comment: @muruga5000 the question your given link is not consists the solution what i am asking. I need to add items to floating action bars with description.

Answer (score 0):

After finish my searching , i am decide to use [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) library to achieve such effect what i need. I didn't find any native library to do this.