# Android FAB not at right place

Tags: android, layout

My Floating button is not aligned where I want it. I want it next to the InputBox but also a bit more down on the layout. It is currently a bit above the InputBox 
I have seen the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library/30609927#30609927) and I have tried it but I could't get it working, Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fsend"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:fabSize="mini" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Write message here"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fsend"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_reciever"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/chat_input" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/fsend"
            android:dividerHeight="16dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot[image: screenshot]

EDIT 1:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Write message here"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fsend"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_reciever"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/chat_input" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/chat_input"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
      android:id="@+id/fsend"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:tint="@android:color/white"
      app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
      app:fabSize="mini" />
```

Comment: put fab and edittext in horizontal linearlayout, and align fab and edittext in center of linear layout, then align this linearlayout to parentBottom.

Comment: The fab then disapears

Comment: set EditText's width, in ur current layout it is match_parent, so it will occupy all space and push fab out of screen,

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/chat_input"` in your `fab` view it would do the work.

**ATTENTION :** you must swap the position of your `fab` and your `edittext` in your xml file.

Comment: Didn't work, I am now trying what the guy in comments suggested

Comment: oh...sorry to hear that, let me know if that worked.
And if it didn't work, I may have other solutions for your problem

Comment: His suggestion removed the fab completely :(

Comment: @DonaldJansen you want it a little more close to input box yeah??

Comment: the fab is slightly higher than the edittext, so I want the fab to go down slightly

Comment: my approach make it in the same level as the edit text.
I'll change it now, and let me know the result.

Comment: I think I my do it wrong, but if I add 'android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/chat_input"' then the fab goes under the chat_input and stretches the width of the screen, see my updated question below is the change that I made

Comment: @DonaldJansen what if you remove these 2 lines?

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
`android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`