# Cant use FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

i have created and android project in my xml file there is a floating bar like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in my activity i have use like below

```
FloatingActionButton btnCart;
```

and in side on create

```
btnCart = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_cart);
```

when i go to that page app will crash I dont know what did I do wrong

Comment: remove background tint

Comment: post stacktrace please

Comment: What is your error.Share error log

Comment: it works when i remove background tint can you tell me why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FloatingActionButton example with Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828101/cant-use-floatingactionbutton/47829053#comment82618397_47828101) remove android:backgroundTint. You can change background color in following ways:

In XML with attribute app:backgroundTint

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Or in java file

```
btnCart.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(your color in int));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error will be in this line:

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
```

Make ur changes in the third line of code as:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
```