# Cannot resolve symbol 'FloatingActionButton'

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

Recently I have downloaded a code from GitHub and synced it with my android studio. I have faced lots of errors and issues while doing so and somehow fixed most of them. However, the last issue I'm stuck at right now is that my android studio cannot find the class **FloatingActionButton** as you can see in this screenshot
[image: screenshot]

It is to be noted that earlier many other classes, including 'AppCompatActivity' could not be resolved. Changing the dependencies to following solved the issue

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But even after changing dependencies, clean building the project, doing 'Invalidate Caches / Restart...', the problem with 'FloatingActionButton' is still there.

You can check the repository [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud845-Pets)
And this is the [java code of the activity](https://pastebin.com/bPMDFs4z) where the error is occurring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The FloatingActionButton is in the design library.

Add this line to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

This post also has more general info about `FloatingActionButton`: [FloatingActionButton example with Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576450/floatingactionbutton-example-with-support-library)

Answer (score 1):

@Sub 6 Resources already answered this question wholly but I want to add a bonus tip. If you already added `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` to your code and the compiler can't still resolve the FloatingActionButton class, simply **rebuild your project**. A colleague and I recently had this same problem while the dependency was already there and a simple rebuild solved it all.

Answer (score 1):

**Update for AndroidX:**

The answer of @Sub 6 Resources was perfect before androidX was introduced. Now, it is better to include the following dependency instead of the accepted answer's dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

NOTE: It will not be the latest version by the time you are reading this. You can check the version here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases